# Nesterov vs. momentum gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, theano

I implemented these two methods in a deep learning project where I am using theano.  I understand the mathematical difference between these two methods, and my conceptual understanding is that nesterov is an improvement over momentum.

My question is: are there practical situations where momentum descent would be preferred over nesterov?  My experience is that nesterov is always better.  What would be a situation in which I would use momentum?

Comment: related: [What's the difference between momentum based gradient descent, and Nesterov's accelerated gradient descent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/179915/215801)