# Is NAG always better than 'Classical' Momentum?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent

I am currently trying to implement Nesterov Accelerated Gradient (NAG) in a neural network following the description shown [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/).

My understanding is that it is identical to 'Classical' momentum (CM), also shown in the link above, except that the gradients are calculated on `weights += mu * v`.

That seeming simple enough, I implemented this and to my surprise it seems that NAG doesn't always outperform CM (typically only a small improvement if any).  In fact, I am often seeing CM outperform NAG!  This seems wrong to me.

**Is this expected behavior?**  I have looked at multiple other questions here on NAG and I'm pretty sure my code is sound.

Here is the relevant code (I know my `calculate_gradients` function works correctly, among other code excluded).  The part I don't know for sure is everything outside the gradient calculations in the while loop.  Have I perhaps missed something?

```
# use_nesterov = TRUE
# vt.old = 0
# mu = 0.9

while (epoch < stepmax){

    # update function
    vt = (mu * vt.old) - (learningrate * gradients)
    weights += vt

    vt.old = vt

    # other non-relevant code
    ...

    # calculate gradients
    gradients = calculate_gradients(
                    if (use_nesterov) {weights + mu*vt.old} else {weights}, 
                    ...)
}
```

Comment: Related: [Nesterov vs. momentum gradient descent](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183650/12359)